# Refresh gallery after renaming/ deleting of images in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating an image in DCIM/Camera (default directory), after creating I am deleting the original filename and rename the newly created image to the deleted filename like

```
OriginalFileName- image04.jpg
NewFileName - image04(1).jpg
```

Deleting the OriginalFile, now the structure will look like this

```
OriginalFileName - //Deleted
NewFileName - image04.jpg
```

The above is working great but when I open gallery I saw a blank image with the name of `image04(1).jpg` but in the file manager, it doesn't exists.

How do I refresh the gallery after doing the above stuff.
Note: The blank image wasn't created when I do processing in Internal Storage, this only happens with external SD card storage (external memory card slot).

I am using Android Marshmallow, I found that in Lolipop doesn't create any blank image.

How to rectify that.

Edit:
I used `ContentResolver.Delete(sourceURI, null, null);` but it throws exception.

sourceURI: `{content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/D660-18BD%3A/document/D660-18BD%3AAlbum%201%2F20180423_184057%20(1)%20(1).jpg}`

Exception:

```
{Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Delete not supported
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualIntMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00089] in <e8c0e16a54534fa885244f0ad837c79e>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualInt32Method (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0001f] in <e8c0e16a54534fa885244f0ad837c79e>:0 
  at Android.Content.ContentResolver.Delete (Android.Net.Uri url, System.String where, System.String[] selectionArgs) [0x00068] in <e79c73bcbbb547688bef6c7e9665c95e>:0 
  at iPro.Droid.ResizePicActivity+<>c__DisplayClass35_0+<<StartProcessing>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x00ddf] in H:\Android App\myapp\myapp.Android\ResizePicActivity.cs:583 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException stack trace ---
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Delete not supported
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(ContentProviderNative.java:544)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1380)
}
```

Comment: @EvZ, I had already seen that link earlier and that was not working, that's why I had posted my question. Both the questions are not identical, in my case I am renaming the file which needs to be refreshed in gallery.

Comment: I got the answer..

// after deleting the original file, call the below code
// where fileName is not URI, its fully qualified path
`Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.DeleteMediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data + "=?", new string[] { fileName });`

Comment: // after renaming file call the below code
`MediaScannerConnection.ScanFile(Android.App.Application.Context, new string[] { oldFileName, newFileName }, null, null);`

Comment: Hope, someone found this useful when he stuck :)